# Oracle 12c settings?

Tags: oracle12c

I am relatively new to Oracle 12C, I have question about default settings. What I want actually whenever inserting new data in db to be saved in upper case regardless how was entered in initial query. How to change settings to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better suited on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Create  a trigger

Comment: Thank you guys I have placed question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DKCroat What version of 12c?  12.2 has some new features for case sensitivity.

Comment: @JonHeller I am using  Version 3.2.20.10

Comment: Version 3 came out around 1983; please double check your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger that upon any insert statement will fire a function to convert the entire column to uppercase.

UPDATE
  Customers
SET
  FirstName = UPPER(FirstName)